# How can I force Apache POI to use cell formats when auto sizing columns?

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I am using Apache POI to generate Excel spreadsheets (.xlsx).  Many of my cell styles contain data format strings, but when columns containing such styles are auto-resized the column width is based on the unformatted cell contents.

Example:

```
DataFormat format = wb.createDataFormat();
CellStyle dollars_m = wb.createCellStyle();
dollars_m.setDataFormat(format.getFormat("_($* #,##0.0,,\"m\"_);_($* (#,##0.0,,\"m\");_(@_)"));
```

A cell value of 123456789.01 will resize as though the cell contained 12 characters rather than the eight ($ 123.5m) it will actually contain.

I am able to force formula's to resolve themselves before auto-resizing, is there a method which will force formats to apply?

Comment: Apache POI already tries to format the cell based on the format string applied to it, before autosizing it. See [line 156 of SheetUtil](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/poi/trunk/src/java/org/apache/poi/ss/util/SheetUtil.java). Are you sure you've got the right fonts installed on the machine you're auto-sizing on, and you're running the latest version of Apache POI?

Comment: That project was on 3.9, I moved it to 3.10.  The behavior changed in 3.10, it is now too narrow for formula cells.  When I `evaluateInCell` all cells before calling `autoSizeColumn` then the columns are all properly sized.

Comment: Ah, yes, it works on the cached formula value. You will need to have the formula result calculated before it'll know what the value is to size against

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of 3.10 Apache POI now applies formats before determining the width of a column in `autoSizeColumn`.  Formula cells must be evaluated using `DataFormatter#evaluateInCell` before `autoSizeColumn` is called otherwise the width will be based on the cached formula result.